# change the format of the text of matplotlib clabel

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting the contour of air pressure.
In general, if the pressure is 1013 hPa, in contour, it will shows 13, if the pressure is 997, it will be 97, i.e., I need to get the last two char.

I can use

```
plt.clabel(c, fmt="%.2s")
```

and I can get the first two char, but I do not know how to get the last two word.
please help me to to solve this problem, thank you.

Comment: The example in the [official reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contour_label_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-contour-label-demo-py) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The format can be a function that given a value returns the formatted string.

Here is an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter

Z = gaussian_filter(np.random.rand(100, 150), sigma=12) * 1000 + 500

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 4))

CS1 = ax1.contour(Z, cmap='inferno')
ax1.clabel(CS1, CS1.levels)
ax1.set_title('Default labels')
ax1.set_xticks([])
ax1.set_yticks([])

CS2 = ax2.contour(Z, cmap='inferno')
ax2.clabel(CS2, CS2.levels, fmt=lambda x: f'{x:.0f}'[-2:])
ax2.set_title('Using two last digits')
ax2.set_xticks([])
ax2.set_yticks([])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: custom formatting clabel]

PS:
In `fmt=lambda x: f'{x:.0f}'[-2:]`, `lambda x: f'{x:.0f}'[-2:]` is a way to write a function that given `x` returns the corresponding string.

`fmt=lambda x: f'{x:.0f}'[-2:]` would be similar to
`fmt=mydisplayfunc` with

```py
def mydisplayfunc(x)
   string_result = f'{x:.0f}'  # converts the number x to a string without decimals
   two_last_digits = string_result[-2:]  # takes the two last characters of the string
   return two_last_digits
```

You might want to read more about [lambda functions](https://realpython.com/python-lambda/) and [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).

Comment: Good solution but I would like to understand more to adapt it to my problem. Could you explain the line: 
fmt=lambda x: f'{x:.0f}'[-2:] ?

Comment: I just added some more explanation.